# What does 弹性 refer to in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

This text discusses '人体运动到底有没有极限？‘

人的心理因素弹性很大，积极的精神状态可以激发身体潜能，从而让运动员在竞赛中超水平发挥。

弹性： 物体受外力作用发生形变、除去作用力能恢复原来形状的性质 （zdic.net)
弹性： flexibility, elasticity

However, I don't think they want to say 'the mind is flexible' or 'psychological factors are flexible'.

I think 弹性 means here 'ability to stretch, make elastic, increase', but I'm not really sure.

1. 人的心理因素弹性很大,
   Psychological factors have a great ability (性） to 'stretch, increase'（弹 (our sporting ability)),
2. 积极的精神状态可以激发身体潜能
   a positive outlook can unleash our body's hidden power,
3. 从而让运动员在竞赛中超水平发挥。
   and so allow the athlete in competition to display greater than normal ability.

Comment: Forget about it, this is not a good sentence. 他想说的是"人的心理变化范围很大, 其影响也很大"

Comment: I'm glad you said that, because it was driving me crazy! "人的心理变化范围很大" is easy to understand.

Comment: scalability. Some IT infrarchitecture requires scalability, that is to say, we can add some basic components like hardwares to extend throughput of the IT system, 弹性 here does just means same feature, with some excitations, he can work better.

Answer (score 5):

《汉语大词典》

> 2.比喻事物的可多可少、可大可小等伸缩性。

《懒虫简明汉英词典》

> flexibility

人的心理因素(的)弹性很大
The flexibility of human's psychological factors is great.

If a doctor tells a healthy man that he has cancer, he will get sick very soon.
If a woman has cancer, and the doctor tells her that she is healthy, she can live longer and healthier.

This is the psychological effect.

人的心理因素弹性很大 also talks about this effect.

All coaches encourage the athletes before the competitions because an athlete may be confident or without confidence.

The 弹性 here refers to this range, active or passive.

Comment: 到底这句话‘人的心理因素(的)弹性很大’是什么意思？

Comment: '弹性'翻译为‘range'?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the later context (积极的精神状态可以激发身体潜能，从而让运动员在竞赛中超水平发挥。) explains 弹性 pretty well.  Reversely, if 运动员的精神状态不好，他就很难在竞赛总发挥得好。 In brief, 运动员发挥的好不好 fluctuates with his 精神状态, hence 精神状态 has 弹性。

Comment: 如果只写‘积极的精神状态可以激发身体潜能，从而让运动员在竞赛中超水平发挥。’我没有什么问题。为什么写‘人的心理因素弹性很大,’？ ‘伸缩性’和‘精神状态变动’不一样的。 'flexible' is not 'fluctuate'.

Comment: 如果说：“心理因素  在激发身体潜能方面  弹性很大” 这句话你能理解吗？

Comment: ok, let me explain this way. 心理因素 refers to 精神状态. So, if 精神状态 from high(好) to low（坏）, 运动员的发挥 will go from 好 to 坏. you could consider 弹性 as resilience, you could imagine a spring, when you press it and it will try to return to its previous shape. The more you press, the more resistance you will get from it. Analogically, the better 精神状态 could be, the better 运动员的发挥 could be. And vice versa.

Comment: I will translate 人的心理因素弹性很大 as The psychological factor plays an important role or The psychological factor can affect a lot.

Comment: That really is 'interpreting'! 翻译‘弹性’为‘plays' 但是对我来说‘人的心理因素’和‘精神状态’不一样的。 人的心理因素就是’因素‘不是’人的精神状态。‘上面Jacob13说的“Forget about it, this is not a good sentence.”你怎么看？

Comment: 我认为第一句话仔细体会好像是有点问题。但是如果你不去仔细深究的话，还是可以很容易理解的。一般人可能不会去深究‘心理因素’和‘精神状态’的具体关系。 可能只有学习心理学专业的人士才能解释清楚。如果第一句话改成“人的心理因素 影响 很大”（The psychological factor plays an important role ），可能会好一些吧。

Comment: 还有一点，我不是把‘弹性’翻译成‘plays’, 我是按照我对语义的理解翻译的。 不是对应每个词来翻译的。我认为这样翻译更准确一些。

Answer (score 1):

指心理因素对结果的影响相关性很大。
积极的状态有正面的影响，消极的状态有负面的影响，但是又没有明确客观的具体数据，这时候用弹性来表达一种定性的不确定的相关性关系。

Comment: 只是‘心理状态’积极的或者消极的就是全部的‘心理状态’而不是‘心理因素’。因素不构成完整的状态。你觉得在这句话中用的‘弹强’是正确的？ 用英语为‘flexibility' 但是怎么可能有’flexible mental factors'?? zdic.net 有’弹性： 物体受外力作用发生形变、除去作用力能恢复原来形状的性质‘ 你自己怎样定义‘弹强’呢？

Comment: 语言不是科学，不能非黑即白地定义为正确或者不正确。如果你是参与考试，你可以认为这样的表达不严谨不正确。如果你只是想知道说话人表达的意思，就像我这样理解就可以了。

Comment: "不能非黑即白地定义"真的！总是我的错误！